# Sort items in a list in vim

Tags: python, vim

Suppose I have a python list:

```
values = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

And I want to sort this alphabetically, so that it ends up like this:

```
values = ['five', 'four', 'one', 'three', 'two']
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this in vim? The way that I was currently doing it is:

- regex split `s/,/,\r/g` --> newline after every comma
- Normalize spaces on each line: `s/\s//g` (since no spaces are needed here)
- sort the lines, `:sort`
- put the values back on one one line, something like `V` `/]` `J`

This seems quite long-winded, and actually I can probably re-sort these by sight a bit faster than using all the commands above (probably up until the list is about 20 items long). What would be the best way to do this then?

Comment: `print(values.sort)` then copy-paste

Comment: @YangHG yes, I know. That's what I did to type in the question, but I'm seeing if there is something more vim-ish that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing which comes to my head:

1. Visually select the whole list `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']`
2. Press `c<C-R>=`
3. Input and evaluate expression: `=string(sort(`<kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>`))`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Obviously, this works because VimScript has the same syntax for List as Python.